# Why is the H1 overflowing my containers, when I shrink the page verticaly

Tags: html, css, layout, resize

I am having a problem with overflowing text. I am trying to create portfolio with several pages, that will take 100% of user's screen. Everything goes nice and easy, but I have noticed that when I go to dev tools the page goes wild when I shrink the page verticaly. The elements starts to overflow their containers.. even though the width is still ok. I thought the problem was that I had 100 vh on each page, so I removed it and went the way with html,body{height:100%, width:100%}, but that wasn't the problem.

1# EDIT: I can see that if I put min-height:300px for example, then it fixes the problem, but why I cant set min-height: 100% ? I dont want to put some random pixels

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7abd1pLr/1/

HTML

```
<div class="first-page">
        <header class = "header">
            <p>KONTAKT</p>
        </header>

        <main class = "main">
            <div class="portfolio">
                <p class="first-line">POR</p>
                <p class="second-line">TFO</p>
                <p class="third-line">LIO</p>
            </div>

            <div class= "blank"></div>
            <div class= "text">
                <h1>JOHN DOE</h1>
                <h2>ARCHITECTURE STUDENT</h2>
            </div>
            <!--<div class= "blank2"></div>-->
        </main>

        <footer class= "footer">
            <img src="images/mesto.svg" alt="" srcset="">
        </footer>

        <section class = "page-navigation">
            <button class="page-1 button-active"></button>
            <button class="page-2 "></button>
            <button class="page-3"></button>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="second-page">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class= "text-main flex">
                <div class="skills">
                    <h1>SKILLS</h1>
                    <div class="text-sub">
                        <p>Photoshop</p>
                        <p>Illustrator</p>
                        <p>InDesign</p>
                        <p>Rhino</p>
                        <p>SketchUp</p>
                        <p>Lumion</p>
                        <p>3D max</p>
                        <p>AutoCad</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="education">
                    <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
                    <div class="text-sub">
                        <h2>some text</h2>
                        <p>some text</p>
                        <br>
                        <h2>some text</h2>
                        <p>some text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="experiences">
                    <h1>EXPERIENCES</h1>
                    <div class="text-sub">
                        <P>some text</P>
                        <p>some text</p>
                        <p>some text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="about-me">
                    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
                    <div class="text-sub">
                        <p>some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="profile-pic">
                <img src="images/.svg" alt="profile" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .flex {
      display: flex; }


    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%; }

    body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.6;
      color: black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-weight: 300; }


    .first-page {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative; }

      .first-page .main {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: 2; }


    .second-page {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #DCDCDC; }

      .second-page .flex {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: flex-end; 
}
        .second-page .flex .text-main {
          height: 80%;
          min-height: 80%;
          align-self: flex-end;
          flex: 0 0 55%;
          flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

Comment: Too much going on in your code. Please narrow the problem to a specific area. Try removing all code that doesn't relate to the problem.

Comment: ok I have narrowed it

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/fxzb53n6/

Comment: Unfortunately not :(, the .first-page .main still overflows, when you shrink the page verticaly

Comment: You have `.main` positioned with `top: 30%`. Not clear what you want it to do.

Comment: I wanted to push the text 30% from top. Should I have used margin top / transform: translateY instead?

Comment: Your method is fine for that purpose, but what do you want `.main` to do when the screen shrinks vertically?

Comment: just to stay in place, where it is. Now it goes all the way to the second page and I dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it happens because of `55%` in `flex: 0 0 55%;` in `.second-page .flex .text-main`

Comment: Maybe, but if you have a look on the .first-page .main, it overflows the content too. So far the only "solution", that made the desired effect was to add .first-page, .second-page{ min-height:800px}  ...